# automatic provisioning failed xamarin.ios vs2022 without a mac

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, ios-provisioning

this issue is giving me a very hard time. i am trying to test my ios app on a physical device. i read that i have to get enrolled in apple developer program and i did. i added it to my apple accounts in visual studio and enabled automatic provisioning but i keep getting that it failed with this error: `Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error       No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. Please enable Automatic Provisioning from the iOS Bundle Signing page.    App2.iOS`. i tried generating certificates using appcircle and importing them to vs but i keep getting asked for a password for the .p12 file that i created. the thing is that i don't remember being asked to set a password for it. in addition, i don't have a create certificate option in apple accounts in vs i only have import certificate. i am so confused. any suggestions? thanks in advance

this is what i get when i try hot restart
[image]

i also checked the logs and found this:

````
i also checked the logs and found this: ```Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient Error: 0 : An error occurred on the receiver while executing a post for topic xvs/idb/auto-provision and client vs14084ALNOO
Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client IDBLocal while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/auto-provision ---> System.NotSupportedException: The Apple Developer Portal web API for creating certificates is no longer supported. Please create your certificate manually.
   at Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.CreateCertificate.<Run>d__9.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/ProvisioningTasks/CreateCertificate.cs:line 69
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---```
````

Comment: Use [Hot Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart) to test on iOS device without a mac. OR investigate cloud-based macs. Azure and other cloud services offer that. (The "Automatic Provisioning" approach you are attempting, requires a mac.)

Comment: thanks for replying sir. but i've tried hot restart and it also needs automatic provisioning and whenever i add my account i get that automatic provisioning failed. i attached a photo to show the error

Answer (score 1):

This issue is currently `being investigated` [in this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/:-0xe8008015-A-valid-provisioning-profi/10073337).

Please follow up with [that thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/:-0xe8008015-A-valid-provisioning-profi/10073337) closely as our team will provide an update if either more information is needed, a workaround is available, or the issue is resolved.